# ios 14 widget: How to reload timeline after UserDefaults changed

Tags: ios, widget, reload, timeline, userdefaults

I have a ios 14 widget that refresh every 5 minutes

```swift
let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
```

The `entries` depends on the configuration on my MainApp.

I use `UserDefaults` to share data between MainApp and Widget.

```
@AppStorage("FollowingCatalog", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.vn.f19.com"))
var catalogItemsData: Data = Data()
```

I've successfully mirrored the widget content base on `UserDefaults` data. BUT my problem is the my widget refresh the UI only after .atEnd policy, every 5 minutes

That cause a bad UX

How can I refresh widget content immediately right after my configuration in `UserDefaults` was changed?

Thanks for your supports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Keeping a Widget Up to Date by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date), to inform your widgets to update its timeline and its content, you call:

```
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
```

This reloads all widgets that your app has. If you want to reload a specific widget (in the case your app has multiple different widget types), use `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "com.myApp.myWidget")` instead.

Comment: I solved the problem yesterday, initially I try to call `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` from widget instead of my main app :D

Answer (score 5):

To clarify the whole workflow, I add some note here:

You can call `WidgetCenter` not only from `widget` but from your main app.

```
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "com.myApp.myWidget........")
```

So the flow is:

1. User change something on MainApp, eg: I rearrange the stock items in the following list
2. MainApp save the data to `UserDefaults`, eg: save the list item order
3. MainApp trigger reload widget by:

   ```
   WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "mone24h_widget")
   ```

   You can get the `kind` by looking into your widget entry file:

   ```
   @main
   struct mone24h_widget: Widget {
      let kind: String = "mone24h_widget"
   ```
4. Widget will reload the timeline, I will get the shared data from `UserDefaults` here. Done the work. Eg: Re-render my stocks list base on the arrangement passed from MainApp

Answer (score 1):

BTW, if you're using react-native, I've already created a module to support this issue:

[react-native-widget-bridge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-widget-bridge)